# Generating a random, fixed-length byte array in Go

Tags: arrays, go, random, slice

I have a byte array, with a fixed length of 4.

```
token := make([]byte, 4)
```

I need to set each byte to a random byte. How can I do so, in the most efficient matter? The `math/rand` methods do not provide a Random Byte function, as far as I am concerned.

Perhaps there is a built-in way, or should I go with generating a random string and converting it to a byte array?

Comment: 1. You have a byte slice (not an array). 2. Don't worry about efficiency until needed. 3.) Consider crypto/rand instead of math/rand (or seed math/rand from crypto/rand occasionally). 4) io.ReadFull is handy.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> [Package rand](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/)
>
> ```
> import "math/rand"
> ```
>
> [func Read](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Read)
>
> ```
> func Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Read generates len(p) random bytes from the default Source and writes
>   them into p. It always returns len(p) and a nil error.
>
> f[unc (*Rand) Read](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand.Read)
>
> ```
> func (r *Rand) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Read generates len(p) random bytes and writes them into p. It always
>   returns len(p) and a nil error.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    token := make([]byte, 4)
    rand.Read(token)
    fmt.Println(token)
}
```

Output:

```
[187 163 35 30]
```

Comment: call rand.Seed() before rand.Read, otherwise you will get the same output each run

Comment: For newer versions of go `math/rand` is considered deprecated and `crypto/rand` should be used instead.

Answer (score 19):

Go 1.6 added a new function to the [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) package:

```
func Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

which fills the passed `byte` slice with random data. Using this [`rand.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Read):

```
token := make([]byte, 4)
if _, err := rand.Read(token); err != nil {
    // Handle err
}
fmt.Println(token)
```

`rand.Read()` has 2 return values: the number of "read" bytes and an (optional) [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error). This is to conform with the general [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) interface, but the documentation of `rand.Read()` states that (despite its signature) it will never actually return a non-`nil` error, so we may omit checking it, which simplifies it to this:

```
token := make([]byte, 4)
rand.Read(token)
fmt.Println(token)
```

Don't forget to call [`rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) to properly initialize it before you use the `math/rand` package, e.g.:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```

Note: Prior to Go 1.6 there was no `math/rand.Read()` function, but there was (and still is) a [`crypto/rand.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Read) function, but the [`crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) package implements a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator, so it is much slower than `math/rand`.

Comment: `rand.Read` always returns `nil` error, so there's no need to handle it - even if it's a respectable habit... :)

Comment: @Aedolon Yeah, just added that.

Answer (score 16):

Using math.Rand means that you are using the system CSPRNG that your operating system provides. This means using /dev/urandom/ and Windows’ CryptGenRandom API.
Go’s crypto/rand package, thankfully, abstracts these implementation details away to minimise the risk of getting it wrong.

```
import(
   "crypto/rand"
   "encoding/base64"
 )

// GenerateRandomBytes returns securely generated random bytes. 
// It will return an error if the system's secure random
// number generator fails to function correctly, in which
// case the caller should not continue.
func GenerateRandomBytes(n int) ([]byte, error) {
     b := make([]byte, n)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    // Note that err == nil only if we read len(b) bytes.
    if err != nil {
       return nil, err
   }

   return b, nil
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's correct that `math.rand` is using a cryptographically secure PRNG. https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand says _package `rand` implements pseudo-random number generators unsuitable for security-sensitive work._

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of go `math/rand` is considered deprecated and `crypto/rand` should be used instead. Cited from it's doc: `rand.Read is deprecated: For almost all use cases, crypto/rand.Read is more appropriate`

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    token := make([]byte, 4)
    rand.Read(token)
    fmt.Println(token)
}
```