# How to make Golang seed init stronger

Tags: security, go, random

I will see people use this method to random seed init for Go to make random!

```
func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
}
```

I am 100% sure this method is not safe,
guess `time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()` is 1000X> easy then find real generated random password

Does any one have an idea, also call windows api to generate random seed is good idea I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If security is important to begin with, then you should "drop" [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) and use [`crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) in the first place.

If security is "not" important, then seeding with `time.Now().UnixNano()` is perfectly fine. (Note that it is needless to call [`Time.UTC()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UTC) because [`Time.UnixNano()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnixNano) returns the Unix time which is specified to be in UTC.)

Note that there are `2592000000000000` nanoseconds in 24 hours, so even if the day is known, theoretically there are 2.592*10<sup>15</sup> different seed combinations, perfectly enough for non-secure scenarios.

[`rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) is to seed the global [`Rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand) of the `math/rand` package. You don't have to (you can't) seed the `crypto/rand` package.

See possible duplicate: [Generate random string WITHOUT time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871104/generate-random-string-without-time/53871127#53871127)

See related questions:

[Generating a random, fixed-length byte array in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781197/generating-a-random-fixed-length-byte-array-in-go/35781334#35781334)

[How to get a sample of random numbers in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274283/how-to-get-a-sample-of-random-numbers-in-golang/50274467#50274467)

Comment: I will use already (crypto/rand) and not (math/rand) i am sure time.Now().UnixNano() is not fine and look stronger alternative!

Comment: if someone find which day you use it, so easy to guess it :) or bad guy can try brute last day, week unix time nano

Comment: @LordZeus [`rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) is to seed the global `Rand` of the `math/rand` package. You don't have to (you can't) seed the `crypto/rand` package.

Comment: wanna learn more, can you write or external link about how example to random []byte create?

Comment: @LordZeus Added some links to the answer.